# Big O notation for infinity worst case

Tags: javascript, big-o

So I wrote a small program that tries to return an array of random, yet unique, values. Meaning that the values will be random but they will not repeat.

Here is the code

```
const randArr = (length) => {
  let a = [];
  let usedNums = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < length; ) {
    let randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (length * 1.5));
    if (!usedNums[randNum]) {
      a.push(randNum);
      usedNums[randNum] = randNum;
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  return a;
}; // makes a random array of size "length" which contains unique values in a random pattern.
```

Clearly the time complexity and space complexity depends on the input but if you look closely, 'I' is only increased if the number is not already in the newly created array. This means that in the worst case scenario, even though the numbers are somewhat random, you could get the same numbers over and over again which means that this could stretch all the way to infinity.

You can tweak the code to make this happen as well
`let randNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (length * 1.5) % 1);` Notice how every single time you will get the same number which means that 'I' will never get increased thus the loop will keep running forever.

Due to the way this works, and the fact that I am new to speaking about programs in terms of time complexities and space complexities, I am unsure what the big O notation for this code would be. Can someone explain please?

Comment: worst case O(infinity) best case O(n). Yes it could be that you never get the right number, but you can also hit with evey loop the right one

Comment: @Ifaruki, thanks for your response. I thought that would be the answer, but according to google, O(infinity) is not valid. Here is a link to my search https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=ALeKk02mrBt2Iw5rTVWmYJ0SmqNPhJWntQ:1593609799721&q=big+o+for+infinite+loop&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT_paQk6zqAhXxc98KHXviDx4QBSgAegQIDRAm&biw=1440&bih=837